# Limit the prefix vba function to dynamic range

Tags: vba, prefix

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13w-AbgY83g02qHGqBrHr_6N26UkNpWKr/view?usp=sharing)I want to limit below vba code to the column A in dynamic range ONLY. Right now if I enter something outside the range, it shows error and disrupts other functions in Workbook_SheetChange.
I attach my file for easy ref.
Please HELP ! HELP

```vb
    'Formate Column A
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Dim s As String
    Dim arr As Variant

    s = Target.Value
    If s = "" Then
      Target.NumberFormat = "General"
    Else
      With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        arr = Split(Application.Trim(.Replace(s, " ")), " ")
      End With
      Target.Value = arr
      Target.Value = Target.Value * 1
      Target.NumberFormat = """REQ0000000""General"
    End If
```

Comment: Your missing an end if (at least). Include the full code and it will be easier to help you

Comment: This is the full code. You can download my file with the link provided. I need help to modify the code to allow me to input any numerical or alphabetic value as usual if the active cell is not the continous row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    'Excel file link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13w-AbgY83g02qHGqBrHr_6N26UkNpWKr/view?usp=sharing


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        Call Module1.DeleteCheck
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Call Module1.CreateCheck
        'Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
        'Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
            

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
 
    
  Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Agents"
      Exit Sub
    Case Else
  End Select
 
      
  If Target.Column > 4 Or Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

 
  Application.EnableEvents = False
 
  If InStr(1, Cells(Target.Row, "A"), "REQ") <> "" And Cells(Target.Row, "B") <> "" Then
 
        Cells(Target.Row, "C") = ActiveSheet.Name
        Cells(Target.Row, "C").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Cells(Target.Row, "C").Font.Size = 12
        Cells(Target.Row, "C").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        Cells(Target.Row, "D").ShrinkToFit = True
        Cells(Target.Row, "A").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Cells(Target.Row, "A").Font.Size = 12
        Cells(Target.Row, "A").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        Cells(Target.Row, "B").Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        Cells(Target.Row, "B").Font.Size = 12
        Cells(Target.Row, "B").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
      
   End If
 
 
'Formate Column A
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Dim s As String
    Dim arr As Variant

    s = Target.Value
    If s = "" Then
      Target.NumberFormat = "General"
    Else
      With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        arr = Split(Application.Trim(.Replace(s, " ")), " ")
      End With
      Target.Value = arr
      Target.Value = Target.Value * 1
      Target.NumberFormat = """REQ0000000""General"
    End If
  End If
 
 
  'Set Cell Movement within The Range
  'https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/set-movement-of-cells-in-dynamic-range-only.1172539/
   If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
 
  
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Set rng = Intersect(Target, rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count))
    Else
        Set rng = Nothing
    End If
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Column = 2 And Not (IsEmpty(Target)) Then
            Target.Offset(, 2).Select
        Else
            Target.Offset(, 1).Select`enter code here`
        End If
    End If
 
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

  Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Agents"
      Exit Sub
    Case Else
  End Select

  If Target.Column <> 5 Or Application.CountA(Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 2)) < 2 Then Exit Sub
  Cancel = True
  Call Module3.SelectOLE3

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

  Select Case Sh.Name
    Case "Agents"
      Exit Sub
    Case Else
  End Select

  If g_blnWbkShtSelChange Then Exit Sub
  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
      g_blnWbkShtSelChange = True
      Call Module1.CheckSheet
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```